# Java - Display n set of records from the list?

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, iterator

I have a `list` which has around 2000 or more records on screen which actually makes my page slower while it loads.
Now what i am trying to achieve i have two buttons `previous` and `next`. Initially display first 50 records on screen and then after click on `next` display another set of 50 records. I have an attribute(`rowNum`) in my `object` which stores `rownum`.

I know the traditional way of doing it by iterating through `loop`. But is there any faster way of doing it like avoiding loops for every time i fetch next 50 records?
`activeCities` is the list that has 2000 records which i need to iterate with displaying 50 records from it everytime.
Below is the currently working code for me.

```
int rowNum=0;
MyCity myCityObject; 
for(Object[] obj : activeCities) {
    myCityObject = new MyCity();
    myCityObject.setRowNum(rowNum);
    rowNum++;
    myCityObject.setCityUsers((String)obj[0]);
                    myCityObject.setCityPreferenceId(NumberUtil.convert((BigDecimal)obj[1]));
    myCityObject.setHeadOfficeId(NumberUtil.convert((BigDecimal)obj[2]));
    .
    .
    .
    myNewList.add(myCityObject);
    if(rowNum==numberReached)
        break;
}
```

Comment: I have a lot of clarifying questions here.  How are you retrieving this data?  Where are you sending it to - a view through MVC or through REST?

Comment: @Makoto No I have a list which already has 2000 records in it. Considering that as a master list Now i want to display and play with the list only. I have already fetched 2000 records from the view.

Comment: Why are you using a list of arrays? I would suggest creating a City-Object

Comment: The performance killer here AFAIK is the transferring of those 2000 records from the DB to Java.  Once you're already bitten that bullet, how you iterate through the result set is less of a concern.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int) - if it is an arrayList then use subList

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The time required for transferring records from DB to Java is quite fast which is not an issue in my case. While i iterate it in UI its the issue. So i need to display it in chunks.

Comment: Iterating is relatively cheap as compared to the construction cost for the objects you are using. iterating through the listwill need to be done on the list at some point regardless to achieve what you want.

Comment: So then is the issue the time it takes for the REST call from the UI to complete?  This should be the only issue here...finding a spot in your array from which to iterate should be very fast.

Comment: Are you rendering HTML, or do you have a Java GUI (Swing)?

Comment: Rendering the UI using JSF Ajax

Comment: Another option is the prefetch the previous and next pages before the user presses the previous/next button. Ofcourse, this can be done your pages do  not consume much memory and/or memory is not a constraint while running the application.

Comment: Do you need to care about the order of data ? @sTg

Answer (score 2):

Because you said that : it's  master list. It means you don't change that data.
You can convert your list to a map,

The map :

- The key is page number
- The values is a list with 50 records inside

And when you want to get next or go to any page, you just get data by key.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 allows to write the operation as

```
List<MyCity> myNewList = Arrays.stream(activeCities, beginOffset, endOffsetExclusive)
    .map(obj -> {
      MyCity myCityObject = new MyCity();
      myCityObject.setCityUsers((String)obj[0]);
      myCityObject.setCityPreferenceId(NumberUtil.convert((BigDecimal)obj[1]));
      myCityObject.setHeadOfficeId(NumberUtil.convert((BigDecimal)obj[2]));
      .
      .
      .
      return myCityObject;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which isn’t magically accelerating the operation, but it does exactly what is needed, only processing elements, whose `MyCity` instance you will find in the result list.

In principle, you could turn this stream processing to parallel, but converting array elements to an object instance and storing them into a list, can’t be that expensive that it will benefit from parallel processing, even if processing all 2000 elements. I suppose, that actual expensive part is on the db or rendering side or the data transfer between those sides.

Answer (score 0):

In a real world, nobody would iterate over all the records in the memory in order to take first n rows (aka pagination).

Instead, you would like to **filter those records on DB level**, meaning that your SQL query (if you use RDBS of course) should do it all for you.

For instance, if you use MySQL you could try the following query to get records between 50 and 100:

```
SELECT * FROM cities LIMIT 50,100;
```

Or retrieve first 50 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM cities LIMIT 50;
```

Good luck!

Comment: "In the real world" is dependent on the specific situation. If you want to limit the amount of queries (e.g. because the network to the database is slow) and only need to increase UI speed, paging in the front end part (i.e. "in memory") is perfectly fine. Your point is valid of course if the limiting factors are memory consumption or load on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new attribute pageInitialNumber where you store your initial page number which will modify each time user press next or previous with fetch size preferred (50 in your case).Initial is 0.After press next you make it 50.You got the idea. After that need to use in your page the value on each component like activeCities.get(pageInitialNumber+ incrementVariable) where increment variable is something like this

```
 int variableWhichIncrement= -1;    
 public Integer getIncrementVariable(){
     variableWhichIncrement=variableWhichIncrement+1;
     return variableWhichIncrement;
  }
```

U need to reset this variable value after each next or previous pressed also.This way you wont iterate the list . 
Hope this will solve your problem.